# Iterate through checkbox list and assign the values from Database to list as selected if DB has the value

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, selecteditem, checkboxlist

I have an asp.net checkbox list with 10 values and i have inserted 4 checked values to database. Now the values are in database as below

```
1
2
3
4
```

If i want to reassign the values to Checkboxlist as checked. Can someone tell me how to iterate through the checkbox list with the database values and check the ones i get from Database.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. You just need to check the value of the listitem to see if its the same as one(s) in the database. There are many ways you could do this and really depends on the rest of your setup and the connection to your database.

Here is how to iterate through the listbox items (which I think is your real question):

```
   for (int x = 0; x < listBox1.Items.Count; x++)
   {
    if(YOUR LOGIC HERE)
    {
       listBox1.SetSelected(x, true);
    }
   }
```

Hope this helps you!